# Как работает компонент рекомендованные товары Bitrix (catalog.recommended.products)

Tags: битрикс

Я недавно в веб-разработке)
Такой вопрос, как добавляются рекомендованные товары в компоненте catalog.recommended.products
Автоматически или вручную?
Добавил компонент, но что-то он ничего не отображает)
Заранее спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался) список товаров берется из пользовательского свойства по умолчанию RECOMMEND, можно поменять в настройках компонента) Его не будет, создавайте вручную, я сделал тип "привязка элементов по XML_ID".
В Идентификатор товара: указывается ID товара К КОТОРОМУ привязываются рекомендованные товары. (можно дернуть из $arResult)